# Relation between lists of raw text strings and list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, scikit-learn

Reading the documentation for [tokenization with SKLEARN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), I would like to know why there is apparently a difference between a **list of strings** and a **list of raw text strings** in Python.

The SKLEARN documentation gives the following example, which runs perfectly:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['This is the first document.', 'This document is the second document.', 'And this is the third one.', 'Is this the first document?']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

The output is:

```
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```

If you read text as a string from a .txt file, however, and define it as the `corpus`, the error notification is:

`ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.`

Yet the actual type of `corpus` in the SKLEARN example is `<class 'list'>`.

Writing strings from .txt files to lists and ingesting them **triggers the `ValueError` again but gives me a list of tokens at the same time.**

The adjusted code is:

```
import string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text_file=open("[path]\\[file].txt", "r", encoding="latin1")
words=text_file.read() # reads file as string
corpus=[words] # turn string into list
print(type(corpus)) # retrieves: <class 'list'>

# tokenize text

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

So it seems that lists of strings and lists of raw text strings are handled in a different manner.
As this is the first time that I have consciously come across this issue, I would be grateful to learn more.

Comment: sklearn's "raw text document" is not the same thing as Python "raw string".

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. But ```type(corpus)``` retrieves ```<class 'list'>``` in both cases. I will try and find out how to read .txt as as raw text document.

Comment: you may be feeding in a string instead of a list: `"['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']"`, you can convert this into a Python list by calling `json.loads`

Comment: As I only have one .txt document, I was indeed trying to feed in a string but also tried this: ```corpus=[words, "new doc"]``` Now it is ```<class 'list'>```, too, but still triggers the error.

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: Your example from the documentation doensn't look right. You assign `corpus` but use `words`.

Comment: My bad, it has to be corpus.

Comment: I added the adjusted code and feel that there might be an issue with the particular text document I am using as the script returns a proper list before given me the ´´´ValueError´´´ notification. It seems that my single .txt file is read as several lists, which might be due to an encoding error. We had some Russian characters in the original file. I might need to pre-process the file or use some exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the SKLEARN developers for a definition of "raw text document".

This is the [response](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/20151):

> In the documentation "raw text document" means a (regular) Python
> string representing a document with no preprocessing, and a corpus is
> a list (or an iterable) or such strings.
> All that `CountVectorizer` etc care about is that they receive a list
> (or an iterable) of Python strings. We say no "pre processing",
> because some pre-processing is already included in these estimators,
> but really that decision is up to the user.

I will write a PR for the full definition to be included in the documentation.

After removing all Cyrillic characters from the original document, the adapted code shared in my question worked without errors.